# The time component of a geodesic

Tags: coordinate-systems, time, geodesics

A geodesic is the path taken by a falling object so if the person is standing still he is not following a path, he is stationary on a path. This could be called "standing still" on the geodesic.

On a planet which is so far from any suns that there is no gravity from a sun felt on the planet's surface, presumably a person could stand still on the space component of any geodesic that applies to his position. Why can't he stand still on the time component of that geodesic? What is so special about time components of geodesics that prevents him from choosing not to cross it and therefore not to invoke a force?

Comment: What does “stand still on the time component of that geodesic” even mean?

Comment: A geodesic is the path taken by a falling object so if the person is standing still he is not following a path, he is stationary on a path. This could be called "standing still" on the geodesic.

Comment: If the planet was far enough from the sun and not rotating it would still have geodesics and if the person would not be crossing the time geodesic he would feel no weight.

Comment: The gravity we feel on the Earth is not caused by the sun, it is caused by the mass of the Earth itself. Standing on the surface of the Earth we feel weight, because the surface of the Earth is applying force to us (forcing us away from a geodesic in spacetime). An astronaut in orbit, conversely, feels no forces -- they *are* following a geodesic.

Answer (score 3):

The mass of the planet will warp both space *and* time, so no, there is no geodesic in which the person is "standing still" on the planet's surface. The geodesics near the planet either represent orbits around the planet, or else freely falling objects moving towards the center of the planet. If the person hits the surface of the planet, then they're no longer moving on a geodesic, they're being accelerated away from the geodesic (and they will feel this acceleration, i.e. force, as "weight").

Comment: What accelerates him away from the geodesic?

Comment: Whatever force keeps him from falling to the center of the planet. Typically this is the contact force between atoms making up his body and those making up the surface of the planet. Standing on Earth, we can feel the Earth pressing against our feet, and measure this force with an accelerometer (or even a simple scale).

Answer (score 2):

> A geodesic is the path taken by a falling object so if the person is standing still he is not following a path, he is stationary on a path

It seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a geodesic is. A geodesic is a path through spacetime, not just a path through space. A person who is standing still is indeed following a path through spacetime. He is not following a path through space, but standing still does not freeze time. Time continues, his heart continues beating, his watch continues ticking, his potassium-40 continues decaying. There is nothing he can do to stop going to the future. Thus even a person standing still unavoidably continues on a path through spacetime.

If he is standing still on the surface of a planet then his path through spacetime is not a geodesic. He still has a path and cannot avoid having a path through spacetime, but that path is not a geodesic.